# How to integrate react-draft-wysiwyg custom component with React-Final-Form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm trying to learn how to use React-Final-Form (RFF in short).

I've learnt how to use `<Field>` component but now I need to add a custom component to use a WYSIWYG editor which is NOT provided by RFF.

So, I've chosen react-draft-wysiwyg.

Ok, first here my form:

```
const FormComponent = () => {

  const handleSubmitOnClick = () => ({
    news_title,
    news_subtitle,
    editor_content, 
    image_url,
  }) => {

    const data = {
      "user": {
        news_title: news_title,
        news_subtitle: news_subtitle,
        editor_content: editor_content <- here the content from the WYSIWYG editor
        image_url: image_url 
      }
    }

     // API call here .... 
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>News Main Page</h1>

      <Form 
        onSubmit={handleSubmitOnClick()}
      >
        {
          ({ 
            handleSubmit, 
            values, 
            submitting,
          }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-testid="form">
            <Field 
              name='news_title'
              placeholder='News Title'
              validate={required}
            >
              {({ input, meta, placeholder }) => (
                <div className={meta.active ? 'active' : ''}>

                  <input {...input} 
                    type='text' 
                    placeholder={placeholder} 

                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </Field>

            <Field 
              name='news_subtitle'
              placeholder='News SubTitle'
              validate={required}
            >
              {({ input, meta, placeholder }) => (
                <div className={meta.active ? 'active' : ''}>

                  <input {...input} 
                    type='text' 
                    placeholder={placeholder} 
                  />
                </div>
              )}
            </Field>


            <WYSIWYGEditor /> **** HERE THE ISSUE ****

            <MyDropzone />
            <button 
              type="submit"
              className="signup-button"
              disabled={submitting}
            >
              Continue
            </button>

          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
    </>
  )
}

export default FormComponent;
```

This is the Editor file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Components
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html';


// Hooks version of the Class below (done by me)
const WYSIWYGEditor = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
  const onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
    return setEditorState(editorState)
  } 

  return (
    <div className="editor">
      <Editor 
        editorState={editorState} 
        wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
        editorClassName="demo-editor"
        onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
      />
      {
        console.log('editorState => ', draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())))
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default WYSIWYGEditor
```

The `<WYSIWYGEditor />` returns the correct value, no prob there, but I don't how to integrate this component to the RFF flow by using `name='editor_content'` and when the form `submit` button is clicked.

Any help is much appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the solution myself by looking at the React-Final-Form website.

In order to use custom solution OR 3rd Party components with `<Field>` inside your RFF form, you need to add the following:

// main component file with RFF form

```
....

<Field
  name="editor_content"
  component={WYSIWYGEditor}
/>

etc...
```

Please note: do not try to pass the component this way `component={<WYSIWYGEditor />}` otherwise it returns an error about not allowed to pass an Object 
DO NOT forget to import the component :)

The example above will pass `input` and `meta` to the custom component to collect the data and use it in the form, and this is how:

// WYSIWYGEditor file

```
const WYSIWYGEditor = ({ input, meta }) => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
  const onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
    setEditorState(editorState)
    return input.onChange(draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent())))

etc....
  }
```

You'll notice that, in the `onEditorStateChange` function I have been able to use `input` from the props, and by using the `onChange` method I can pass back the returned value to the parent component (RFF form).

I hope this will help someone else.
Happy coding!

Comment: Nice job. For future reference: The only contract needed for RFF to maintain a "controlled" input is that the input accept the current `value` and an `onChange` callback that is called whenever the value changes.

Comment: @ErikR. Thanks for your comment. Would you please provide a snippet of the refactored code with your comments? Many thanks.

Comment: Huh? You said you "found the solution". Not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @ErikR. it is fixed, I was just wondering if your comment was suggesting some refactoring to make the code better. Just that. No worries.

Comment: @Joe How do you set initial value using `htmlToDraft`?

Answer (score 3):

This was extremely helpful. It would've been even more helpful if instead of etc.... you would've put in the full version of your code or close to it. I ended up with this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { EditorState, convertToRaw } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';

// Hooks version of the Class below (done by me)
const WYSIWYGEditor = ({ input, meta }) => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
    const onEditorStateChange = editorState => {
        setEditorState(editorState)
        return input.onChange(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
    }

    return (
        <div className="editor">
            <Editor 
            editorState={editorState} 
            wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
            editorClassName="demo-editor"
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
            />
            {
                console.log('editorState => ', convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default WYSIWYGEditor;
```

Comment: Great! What if I have `initialValues`? How could I pass that in?